# Possible Sign That A Database Is Corrupt?

Tags: sql-server

I have a database that's size is 100GB.  When I run CHECKDB on it, it fails to due a lack of space for tempdb, which has over 1TB of space.  I can restart my SQL Server, flush out tempdb, the drive has 1TB of available space, and run it again, and it will use everything and fail due to a lack of space.

I suspect the database is corrupt because this seems like odd behavior, but is there a scenario where a 100GB database would use more than 1TB for running CHECKDB?

**UPDATE**

The table that didn't pass `DBCC CHECKTABLE`, I recreated its indexes and will see if it verifies faster.

Comment: That seems very unlikely that a 100GB database would overflow an empty 1 TB drive.  What else is using tempdb, if anything?

Comment: @RLF Nothing; I put it on its own server just for this.  Seems very odd.

Comment: The fact that you were able to attach the DB on its own server is at least a sign that the boot page is intact. Can you try running `DBCC CHECKDB WITH ESTIMATEONLY` to see the estimated amount of tempdb usage?

Comment: Is it checking tempDB?  I thought that when you ran checkDB the snapshot database was created on the same drive as the original database data file.  Is there sufficient space on that drive?  Can you post the actual error message?

Comment: @Greg Good idea, right now, I'm running a `DBCC CHECKTABLE` on each table.

Comment: @JonathanFite It's only running out of space on the tempdb drive; the other drives are fine.

Comment: @Greg It says that it needs 1KB.

Answer (score 1):

Normally a few events of 823 and 824 are warnings that there is possible corruption on the database, also if you have backups of this database that are failing and or jobs on it that fail to complete.